# DAO.Recordset performance

Tags: ms-access, vba

If I am going to open a DAO.recordset of a table or a query

would doing something like

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_Some_Table", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

be faster then

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_Some_Table").OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

or

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySomeQuery").OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Or is there no difference, just preference.

Comment: This is the type of question I don't understand. Why not just check it out? It would have taken less time than writing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this to test the timing difference

```
 Dim StartTime As Double
 Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

 StartTime = Timer
```

and at end of module

```
 SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
```

I actually just ran each and here are the results. The query is a SELECT * from the same table i use above. I picked a table I know has about 1 million records too, so hopefully this helps? Sorry I didnt get to this yesterday, some reporting features broke and i had to fix them.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the big difference is because the Jet engine will create a execution plan for a saved query.

Comment: I like how recordsets are the worst LOL

Comment: Well I'm just glad that the method i have been using IS the quickest. Also thanks for taking the time to check it out.