# How can I test the speed of 2 different querying methods in MS Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, time, ms-access-2016

I have a database that is linked to external SQL Server tables. I am playing around with pass-through queries to try and run queries on the server and return the results to my local machine. I'm told that this is faster for tables with tens of millions of rows. However, I want to be able to *prove* to myself that this is faster than a querying using my local machine. How can I display querying time in MS Access? Or if there exists some other way of seeing which query is faster, I'm all ears.

**My code for the pass-through query:**

```
    queryname = "qrypass_AbstrList_QuickInfo"
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(queryname)
    qdf.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=Syteline;Description=Syteline;UID=userID;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=ACW_App;LANGUAGE=us_english;"
    qdf.sql = "SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(lp.lp_num)) as trim_lp, lot.item, lp.loc, lp.whse, lot.lot, lot.qty_on_hand " _
               & "FROM isw_lp As lp inner join isw_lplot as lot on lp.lp_num = lot.lp_num " _
               & "WHERE " & whereclause & ";"

    qdf.ReturnsRecords = True

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_AbstrList_QuickInfo", acViewReport
```

Comment: Use a timer and test, there's no other way.

Comment: You have to use timers, start before procedure and stop after.

Comment: @Whencesoever what would be the start and end point in the VBA code? I'm guessing the start point would be when I do `query.Execute` and the end point would be when I do the first `rst!MoveFirst` ?

Comment: @DarthVoid just before and after each procedure You want to compare. Really we don't see the code so i can't tell.

Comment: why not just execute your query in Sql Management studio? it tells you how much time your query is taking?

Comment: @KashifQureshi I don't have management studio

Comment: @DarthVoid it's a free download...

Comment: @Mat'sMug I don't have management studio *because this is a company laptop and I am not able to/allowed to download anything that they haven't already given me*.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim t as single
t= timer
'do something you want to measure'
debug.print timer -t
```

Timer is not very precise (returns seconds), but that's generally enough for me

Comment: It returns seconds, at `Single` precision - so you get something like `0.02184` seconds - that's good enough for most uses. Multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Select the current time before the query, and again after the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to test the timing difference

```
 Dim StartTime As Double
 Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

 StartTime = Timer
```

and at end of [what you're testing]

```
 SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
```

*This was a copy/paste from my previous answer here: [DAO.Recordset performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796349/dao-recordset-performance/42798330#42798330)*

Comment: Timer returns a `Single`, not a `Double`.

Comment: I think that this site my have plagiarized your answer [.VBA Code To Calculate How Long Your Macro Takes To Run](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/1/28/vba-calculate-macro-run-time) without referencing their source.  You'd think that they would have at least changed some variable names or msgbox text.

Comment: @ThomasInzina I think that article might be older than my previous answer. I got that naming convention off of SO some time ago - so I think it might just be a defacto naming convention for those variables.

Comment: No worries.  I use there code (including url) in several of my post.  I know how code snippets get passed around.  Cheers!